# Bluestacks 4 showing error System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, bluestacks

I just Bluestacks 4 again ( after 4 months ) and after successful boot, on runnig any app it show the Error:
[image]

I had run Bluestacks 4 successfully earlier without any Problem.But I recently disabled "Hyper-V" from the boot menu ( because it was causing Virtual Box to failing to Boot ).Any Help will be granted

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your region formats to English (united states). If it doesn't work, change it to another and then turn back and apply. The region formats change by going to Control Panel → Clock and Region → Change location → Tab format